# Showing that a function is the gradient of another function

Tags: vector-analysis

How do I show that this function;

$ f = \frac{\vec{r}-\vec{X}t}{|\vec{r}-\vec{X}t|^3}$

$\vec{X} = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $\vec{r} = (x,y,z)$

is the gradient of another function?

like so: $ f = \nabla F  $

Comment: Your $f$ cannot be a divergence, because the divergence is a scalar function, whilst yours is a vector one.

Comment: The divergence acts on a vector field to give a scalar field. So that function can't be the divergence of any vector field. (It could, however, be the _gradient_ of a scalar field.)

Comment: Oh.. sorry that's right.. it needs to be the gradient... -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $f$ is:
$$
f(\vec r)=\dfrac{x-x_1t}{\left(\sqrt{(x-x_1t)^2+(y-y_1t)^2+(z-z_1t)^2}\right)^3}\vec i+$$
$$+\dfrac{y-y_1t}{\left(\sqrt{(x-x_1t)^2+(y-y_1t)^2+(z-z_1t)^2}\right)^3}\vec j+$$
$$+\dfrac{z-z_1t}{\left(\sqrt{(x-x_1t)^2+(y-y_1t)^2+(z-z_1t)^2}\right)^3}\vec k$$

Use:
$$
F(\vec r)=\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{(x-x_1t)^2+(y-y_1t)^2+(z-z_1t)^2}}=\dfrac{-1}{|\vec r-\vec Xt|}
$$ 
and find $\dfrac {\partial F}{\partial x}$,$\dfrac {\partial F}{\partial y}$ and $\dfrac {\partial F}{\partial z}$

Comment: Did you find $F(\vec{r})$ by intergrating all three components with respect to their related component? So the $\vec{i}$ term with respect to $x$ and so on.?

Comment: That's the classical way to do. But in this case note that that $f$ is similar to a gravitational or electric field and these have a well known potential.

Comment: What is the reason that we can ignore any constants during the intergration ?

Comment: Obviously also $F(\vec r)+C$ works: the scalar field (potential) is defined up to a constant.

Comment: Great that is what I expected also.